# Post details with an image on Facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, image

I have a function to post details with an image  to Facebook-wall. Its working but the image shown is very small on facebook wall.then How can I change the size of the image on Facebook?

Comment: Upload the large size of image to the Facebook

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:
keep big image in server:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("caption", "Mona Lisa");
    params.putString(   "description","The Mona Lisa...");
    params.putString("picture","http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg");
    params.putString("name", "Mona Lisa");

        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError de) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fbe) {}
        });
```

Comment: ok thank for that. but in my application i was compressed my image after that i want post the image..

Answer (score 0):

If you want upload images to facebook with big sizes, you need use own code.

Create MultipartEntity. Add parts: no_story, description (options) and stream of file:

```
entity.addPart("source", new InputStreamBody(ContentUtils.openAsStream(uri), ContentUtils.getContentName(uri)));
```

Send POST-request (sample code):

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = HttpConnector.createHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    request.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
    StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();

    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        return EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    else
        throw new FaceException(statusLine.toString());
```

Where url is:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/{ALBUM_ID}/photos&access_token={YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN}.

If photo uploaded success, you get response:

```
{"id":"XXXX","post_id":"YYYY"}
```

XXXX - new photo fid. YYYY - post fid at own wall about uploaded photo (may be missing, if you set param "no_story"="0").